# Setting boundary limits for panning/dragging a Zoomable custom relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've implemented zoom and pan/drag functionality in my custom relative layout successfully with the help of following links.

1). An excellent tutorial - [making-sense-of-multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

2). (SO link) [Extending RelativeLayout, and overriding dispatchDraw() to create a zoomable ViewGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378904/extending-relativelayout-and-overriding-dispatchdraw-to-create-a-zoomable-vie/6511296#6511296)

3). (SO link) [Scroll/Panning or drag in custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257321/scroll-panning-or-drag-in-custom-layout)

Here's my full working code.

https://gist.github.com/pandeyGitHub/6805840 .

and my layout.xml looks like this:-

```
<com.myzoomproject.views.ZoomableRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.myzoomproject.views.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_test2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.myzoomproject.views.ZoomableRelativeLayout>
```

My Custom relative layout contains a viewpager and each single page in my viewpager contains 2-4 imageviews (one fullscreen imageview & a couple of **clickable** smaller imageviews). Zooming & panning the page works just fine.

**Problem 1:**
But somehow I'm not able to set **boundary limits** for panning functionality. The page would pan off the screen on overscrolling.

**Problem 2:**
Also, it seems that image-views are panned/translated only in drawing but not in actuality. because they are not clickable anymore the moment they move away from their original position on screen, & the clickable-coordinates remains confined to their original positions only.

I looked up several similar questions on SO [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615173/254567), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458910/254567), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568876/254567) but they all are based on ImageView zoom and not the custom-layout zoom.

So unlike them, I do not have a reference to my imageviews in my ZoomableRelativeLayout. Referencing the Imageviews, reading the bitmaps & displaying them is taken care of by other classes (MyPagerActivity & MyPagerFragment classes). Also, the solution in above mentioned links relies on **matrix transformation**, which i probably cannot use in my case.

Looking forward to any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: did you solve the problem? same for me unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. I've posted my answer below. It's just a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put min/max limits on the `mPosX` & `mPosY` positions - do this after adding `dx` & `dy`.

To work out what limits to apply you could get the child View's size using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, and factor in the current scale.

Answer (score 0):

I've somehow found a workaround to this by some hooks, which is far from being a perfect solution, since I had to hard-code some values. I've added the following code-snippet in my existing code to set the boundary limits to panning. Now the panning works fine.

Logging the mClipBound.top, bottom, left, right values I came up with the following hard-coded values which might work only for 720x1280 & 800x1280 devices.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    ...
    ...

    if (isPortraitMode) {
        if (mClipBound.top < 104 && dy > 0) //104 is a hard-coded value here.
           dy = 0;

        if (mClipBound.bottom > (screenHeight - 77) && dy < 0) // 77 - hardcoded
           dy = 0;
    } else {
        if (mClipBound.top < 0 && dy > 0)
            dy = 0;
        if (mClipBound.bottom > screenHeight && dy < 0)
        dy = 0;

    }

    if (mClipBound.left < 30 && dx > 0) // 30 - hardcoded
        dx = 0;

    if (mClipBound.right > screenWidth && dx < 0)
        dx = 0;

    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;
        ...
        ...
        ...
 }

 ...
 ...


 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    screenWidth = widthSize;
    screenHeight = heightSize;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension((int) (widthSize), (int) (heightSize ));
 }
```

But still i haven't been able to resolve **problem 2:** mentioned in my question above. Some proper adjustments in onMeasure(..) & onLayout(..) methods using mScaleFactor might resolve the issue. But i haven't been able to make it work yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem 2, you have to resize the canvas rect of all your relativelayout´s children. You should do this in onScaleEnd method of your scalegesturedetector.

```
public void resizeChildren() {

    int childCount = this.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

        MyView child = (MyView)this.getChildAt(i);
        child.setScaleFactor(mScaleFactor);
        child.setCanvasRect(mRect);


    }

}
```

setScaleFactor() and setCanvasRect() are methods for MyView which is a custom View I use for finger painting.